# How to change variables using an imported methods function?

Tags: python, multithreading, function

In my code I import another scripts function and call it using threading. In the function I want to change a variable used in the main script. But how is this possible? When I import the main script into the imported script, an error is thrown. Also `global` is useless. Pls help?

My try:

Code file2:

```
import threading
import time


def func():
    time.sleep(3)

    global v 
    v = "b"
```

Code file1:

```
import file2 as f2
import threading
import time


v = "n"

a = threading.Thread(target=f2.func)
a.start()

time.sleep(10)

print(v)
```

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: But how else should I change elements in a function?

Comment: You should pass an object into the function and allow it to change an attribute.

Comment: So how to allow that

Comment: I’ll write another answer which uses parameters instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to see `v` change after three seconds then you need to reference the `v` from `file2`:

Code file2:

```py
import time

v = None

def func():
    time.sleep(3)

    global v 
    v = "b"
```

Code file1:

```py
import file2 as f2
import threading


f2.v = "n"

a = threading.Thread(target=f2.func)
a.start()

time.sleep(10)

print(f2.v)
```

Comment: Ok so the problem now is, that the variable was a tkinter StringVar and when I define it in the other class where all my methods are standing, an error is thrown because I can not define root = Tk().

Answer (score 1):

Another way by making `func` take a parameter:

Code file2:

```py
import time

v = None

def func(m):
    time.sleep(3)

    m.v = "b"
```

Code file1:

```py
import file2 as f2
import threading
import time

class F3:
    v = "f3"

f2.v = "n"
f3 = F3()

a = threading.Thread(target=f2.func, args=(f2,))
a.start()
b = threading.Thread(target=f2.func, args=(f3,))
b.start()

time.sleep(10)

print(f2.v)
print(f3.v)
```

Now `func` can work with anything which has a `v` member.